# Is that possible to import a Swift file from another Swift file

Tags: xcode, swift

Here i am with big trouble to access the method from class a to class b.

I have tried using 
import class a commends but no luck! also setting up with the Swift complier- Search path.

No luck Spend lots number of hours on this issues, so can some one please let me know whether the import package is feasible with swift or not!

Thanks 
Ashok Natarajan

Comment: If they are in the same project you should not have to do anything to be able to use your other class. Just "use" it

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply "use" the class as there is no need to "import it" in any way.

Things that can cause this

1. Is the file where you define the class accessible to your target?
2. Is the file where you define the class have a .swift extension?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Notes, really appreciated. Yes I could access the method one swift class to another swift class without importing...                    But the functions are not accessible when i try to access from UITest.swift

Comment: Ah, make sure you've made that file accessible to the test schema/target.

Comment: Did that work?  You can do so by selecting the file in the file explorer, opening the right sidebar, and making sure your test target check box is selected.  Let me know.